# Is there a reliable way to detect OS of the network hosts from linux workstation?

Tags: linux, monitoring, nmap

How to detect OS of running computers on the network.

We use linux. I want to write wrapper on the python, which will periodically scan network and write results to google spreadsheet. I tried nmap -O and -A, but unfortunately this commands in not reliable. Because

1. It's depend on running services and nmap database of fingerprints.
2. If there are no fingerprints in installed nmap database - scanner cannot determine OS version.

Is there no reliable os detection method for windows/linux hosts with free tools?

Comment: computers can return any info they want so you could never accurately guarantee which `OS` type, and this is done on many servers whereby they'll purposely give you incorrect info to throw you off

Comment: I understand this of course. I want to use this in LAN, where this problem does not exist.

Comment: If you use a [recent version of Nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html) then it is very unlikely it will not have a fingerprint. If it does not, you can [submit one](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect-unidentified.html) and we'll add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a list of what you can read into:

- you could `ssh` in and use `uname -o`
- use you can use `ping` to sort determine `OS`, nice link for some `OS`'s [here](http://www.kellyodonnell.com/content/determining-os-type-ping).
- if your machines are stock then just use `nmap`, it is the definitive project for this.
- or you can read into [IP Stack Fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting) and have a machine intercept packets.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to do it manually, because there is no easy way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pof](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f3/) - a passive operating system detection.

`P0f is a tool that utilizes an array of sophisticated, purely passive traffic fingerprinting mechanisms to identify the players behind any incidental TCP/IP communications (often as little as a single normal SYN) without interfering in any way. Version 3 is a complete rewrite of the original codebase, incorporating a significant number of improvements to network-level fingerprinting, and introducing the ability to reason about application-level payloads (e.g., HTTP).`

Comment: Thank you. That's a good tool, but it's very complicated. I will continue to study it.